# Splitting delimited token list argument

Tags: latex3, expl3, token-lists

I wrote a little piece of code (function `\getfirst:w`) that splits its delimited argument at the first embedded `:`. The code works well if used standalone, but I am unable to place it into the `.code:n` of a key definition. The document command (`\separatethis`) that executes the key evaluation stops with error:

```
! Argument of \getfirst:w has an extra }.
```

What is going wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn\getfirst:w#1:#2\q_stop{#1}
\keys_define:nn{mypkg}{
    myopt .code:n = {
      \tl_set:Nx\myarg_tl{#1}
      \tl_set:Nx\first_tl{\exp_after:wN\getfirst:w\myarg_tl\q_stop}
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\separatethis{O{}}{
    \keys_set:nn{mypkg}{#1}
    \tl_use:N\first_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%works
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\myarg_tl{foo:bar}
\tl_set:Nx\first_tl{\exp_after:wN\getfirst:w\myarg_tl\q_stop}
\tl_use:N\first_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

%doesn't work
\separatethis[myopt=foo:bar]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The colon has category code 11 under `\ExplSyntaxOn`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is catcode, as `:` is a 'letter' inside a code block. You need to use the approach of making the character into a string

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\use:x
  {
    \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \getfirst:w 
      ##1 \token_to_str:N : ##2 \exp_not:N \q_stop
      {##1}
  }
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
    myopt .code:n =
     { \tl_set:No \l_first_tl { \getfirst:w #1 \q_stop } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \separatethis } { O { } }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { mypkg } {#1}
    \tl_use:N\l_first_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\separatethis[myopt=foo:bar]

\end{document}
```

---

In an older version of the answer, I'd suggested using an approach you would in classical TeX programming: use a substitute letter and use a case change to get the right thing in place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\+ } { `\: }
\tex_lowercase:D
  {
    \group_end:
    \cs_new:Npn \getfirst:w #1 + #2 \q_stop {#1}
  }
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
    myopt .code:n =
     { \tl_set:No \l_first_tl { \getfirst:w #1 \q_stop } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \separatethis } { O { } }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { mypkg } {#1}
    \tl_use:N\l_first_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\separatethis[myopt=foo:bar]

\end{document}
```

The team are strongly discouraging this approach in new code: we are removing a direct interface to `\tex_lowercase:D` (hence needing to use a `:D` version above) as this sort of code has nothing to do with case changing!

Answer (score 4):

A different approach could be with regex substitutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_alexg_first_tl
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
 {
  myopt .code:n =
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_alexg_first_tl { #1 }
   \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*?) \: .* } { \1 } \l_alexg_first_tl
  }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand { \separatethis } { O { } }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { mypkg } {#1}
  \tl_show:N \l_alexg_first_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\separatethis[myopt=foo:bar]

\end{document}
```

This will answer

```
> \l_alexg_first_tl=macro:
->foo.
```

You basically are keeping all tokens until the first colon (category code 12) is found and the rest is thrown away. LaTeX3 regular expressions are somewhat different from the POSIX ones, but these are exactly what you'd write in Perl for doing the same thing. The "search string" does

1. `(.*?)\:` matches all characters (tokens, actually) until the first colon is found (the first because of the "nongreedy" quantifier `*?`);
2. because of the parentheses, the matched tokens up to the colon are remembered in `\1`
3. `.* matches all tokens in the token list the search is applied to.

In particular the entire token list is a match for the "search string".

The "replacement" string just replaces all that's been matched with what has been remembered as `\1`.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative approach. I will use it as it is more easily accessible to a non-TeX programmer like me. And I will likely be able to understand it in a year from now.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `?` in the regex part before `\:`? I would use one of `.*` or `.+`.

Comment: I see. Without the non-greedy quantifier, the colon might be swallowed by the first part.

Comment: Why the backslash before the colon? `:` doesn't have a special meaning in regexes, afaik.

Comment: @egreg I think performance should get a mention here: this will be slow compared with my plan :-)

Comment: @AlexG Shows you how much background is important: to me the catcode approach is nice and clear and this is impossible to understand :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Ok, I'll read the corresponding sections in interface3.pdf once more. Hope the knot will burst then.

Comment: @JosephWright I agree on the slowness and I would prefer a "more classical" approach too; however this approach is much more general and can reveal handy in more complex cases.