# Entering infinite loop when defining command with a weird argument

Tags: expl3

I thought that I was following the model offered in
[Splitting delimited token list argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95099/22413).
The only difference is that I did not see the need for using the lower case trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \__aedl_extract_first:w  #1=#2<#3> \q_stop { #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \__aedl_extract_second:w #1=#2<#3> \q_stop { #2 }
\cs_new:Npn \__aedl_extract_third:w  #1=#2<#3> \q_stop { #3 }

\tl_new:N \l_aedl_a_tl
\tl_new:N \l_aedl_b_tl
\tl_new:N \l_aedl_c_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\showComponents}{ m }
    {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_aedl_a_tl \__aedl_extract_first:w   #1 \q_stop
        \tl_set:Nn \l_aedl_b_tl \__aedl_extract_second:w  #1 \q_stop
        \tl_set:Nn \l_aedl_c_tl \__aedl_extract_third:w   #1 \q_stop
         \begin{tabular}{ccc}
          a           & b            & c            \\
         \l_aedl_a_tl & \l_aedl_b_tl & \l_aedl_c_tl 
         \end{tabular}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\showComponents{headrulewidth=8pt<cmd>}

\end{document}
```

Here's the message after I break the infinite loop:

```
! Interruption.
\showComponents ...aedl_extract_first:w #1\q_stop 
                                                  \tl_set:Nn \l_aedl_b_tl \_...
l.32     \showComponents{headrulewidth=8pt<cmd>}
```

But my command is entering into an infinite loop: as best I can tell, my command just keeps expanding `\q_stop`.

One other point: `\showComponents` is supposed to be passed a comma delimited argument.  That is, I want it to accept arguments like

```
\showComponents{headrulewidth=8pt<cmd>,fboxrule=2pt<dim>}
```

The third argument is meant to be a directive to determine whether a command should be redfined or a length should be set.  But for the purposes of this MWE I stripped out the `\clist_map_inline` content.

I know I could do this following @egreg 's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95103/22413) on the same page as posted above, but I would like to know how to get this first attempt at defining my own command with weird arguments to work.

Comment: How about `\tl_set:No \l_aedl_a_tl { \__aedl_extract_first:w   #1 \q_stop }`

Comment: `\tl_set:Nn \l_aedl_a_tl \__aedl_extract_first:w #1 \q_stop` sets `\l_aedl_a_tl` to contain `\__aedl_extract_first:w` and leaves `#1 \q_stop` in the input stream. And since `\q_stop` expands to `\q_stop` you end up in a loop

Comment: So this is just a matter of forgotten `{...}`?

Comment: If you only want the extracted value stored and not literally `\__aedl_extract_first:w #1 \q_stop` you also need to expand the argument once

Comment: the `q` in `\q_stop` warns you it is a quark, quarks are dangerous things to let out on their own. They are all defined like `\def\foo{\foo}` so if you accidentally try to expand one you loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_aedl_a_tl \__aedl_extract_first:w
```

which is not useful at all: `\tl_set:Nn` takes two arguments. Then the tokens

```
headrulewidth=8pt<cmd> \q_stop
```

are left in the input stream and the expansion of `\q_stop` is something one really wants to avoid.

You should say

```
\tl_set:No \l_aedl_a_tl { \__aedl_extract_first:w #1 \q_stop }
```

and similarly for the other two lines. With `o` you expand the first token after the brace.

However there's a simpler way for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \__aedl_extract:w  #1=#2<#3> \q_stop { #1 & #2 & #3 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\showComponents}{ m }
 {
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\
  \__aedl_extract:w #1 \q_stop
  \end{tabular}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\showComponents{headrulewidth=8pt<cmd>}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this approach!